# Onto and One to One Functions

Tags: functions

If we have some functions from $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$: 
$$ SUM(m,n)=m+n\\ PROD(m,n)=m \cdot n\\ MAX(m,n)=\max{m,n}\\ MIN(m,n)=\min{m,n};$$

Which of these functions map $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{N}$ and how can i prove that none of these functions are one-to-one?

Comment: is $N$ the set of natural numbers ?

Comment: yeah it is a set of Natural numbers

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition of $\mathbb{N}$ (does it contain 0?) all of these functions are onto. The easiest way to show this is to explicitly construct a pre-image of each integer.

For example: Fix some integer $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose we want to show that there are $(n, m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $SUM(n,m) = k$.

Then we simply choose $(m,n) = (k, 0)$. It follows that $SUM(k,0) = k + 0 = k$ as desired.

Similarly, let's do the same for $MIN$. It is not hard to see that $MIN(k,k) = k$, so we are done as well.

As for one-to-one, well, you could note that, for example:

$$
SUM(a,b) = a + b = b + a = SUM(b,a) \\
MIN(k,k+1) = k = MIN(k, k+2) = \cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

For showing onto Simon Rose approach for $SUM$ is fine ...similarly for $PROD$ given $n\in \mathbb{N}$ choose $(n,1)$. Its easy to see that none of the above functions is one-one. For example $SUM(2,3)=SUM(4,1)$, $PROD(3,4)=PROD(6,2)$...and so on.